# iOS: Make embedded Tableview "automatically" so big, it doesn't need scrolling but only the parent view does

Tags: ios, tableview

I want an embedded table view within a view. Depending on the user this table has 1-n rows. So the size varies. If I build it right now the table view has to be scrolled if n is too big. I however don't want the tableview scrollable, but I want to make it grow automatically so the user doesn't even see it's a tableview but instead the parent view surrounding the tableview should be scrollable. Or in other words, all rows of the table should be always displayed completely within the parent and depending on n the parent becomes scrollable. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Don't do this. You will end up regretting it. Use the table view to do what you need, the table's header view should help you with this.

Comment: but I want a very complex header and footer. Is there a way of designing a compley header/footer and not only a title?

Comment: the header/footer view are  just view so could be whatever you like

Comment: Have a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableHeaderView

Comment: Thx you 2. But can I create this Header/footer view only programmatically or can I do something in Interface Builder?

Comment: You can create them via Interface Builder just fine